# Disable zoom buttons in Phonegap's inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

After hours of searching and trying different things I'm close to give up. I want to open an external URL in the inAppBrowser that is now included to the Phonegap Build. I remove the address bar with `location=no` (also tried `toolbar=no`, but it didn't do anything), however the zoom (+ and - buttons) that appears whenever you scroll the page won't go away. I can't find a way to disable it, but maybe I overlook something? I'd just use the pinch zoom, so I don't see the reason to have these ugly buttons on top of the page (which is designed specifically for this app).

So is there a way to disable built-in zoom buttons?

I'm testing on Android, but planning to also work on the iPhone version.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but using Cordova instead of Phonegap Build.
The trick that did it for me was to change line 575 of `InAppBrowser.java` to `settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);`.

That won't work for iOS of course, but as far as I know there is no other build in way provided by Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: Cordova 5.1.1: line 619 of {project root}/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/InAppBrowser.java
Note that this doesn't just hide the archaic looking Zoom buttons, but also prevents pinch zooming.

Answer (score 6):

try `zoom=no`

you can find details on cordova inappbrowser plugin documentation: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: This didn't work in Cordova 5.1.1 - it looks like the ability to specify zoom control enablement was removed: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/104

Comment: I found that the zoom=no parameter did not work either, until I ensured that my page (the one contained by inappbrowser) had this in it's meta viewport tag:  user-scalable=no

Comment: Works for Android as well, at least in version 3.0.0+

Answer (score 6):

Using the InAppBrowser plugin, I encountered the same problem.

I managed to hide the +/- "ugly" buttons, but keep the zooming behavior (using pinch gesture) by changing the `InAppBrowser.java` file, and using the following commands :

```
WebSettings settings = inAppWebView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // enable built-in zoom mechanisms
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false); // disable WebView's zoom controls display
```

Found it here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls(boolean)

Answer (score 5):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Use this meta tag in webview external page Thanks...

Comment: Why does this work? To know why it work is more important than just code.

Answer (score 2):

This only remove the zoom button and it is for IOS only:

Open the file in your project:

```
[YourAppName]/platforms/ios/[YourAppName]/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m
```

Find and change from this:

```
[self.toolbar setItems:@[self.closeButton, flexibleSpaceButton, self.backButton, fixedSpaceButton, self.forwardButton]];
```

to this:

```
[self.toolbar setItems:@[self.closeButton, flexibleSpaceButton]];
```

And then build the project with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

try this: `var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,toolbar=no');`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43204929/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder structure root}\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\inappbrowser.java

then search for "zoom", in every place change it zoom="false" it worked for me.

Cordova 10.0.0, Android Studio 4 ,2021

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the options string has to have no spaces between options.
I used:

```
var options  = "location=no,zoom=no";
```

which then enters here:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://treiz.mx', '_blank', options);
```

And now it runs perfect.