# Android Disable zoom button inside a webview

Tags: jquery, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm using InAppBrowser cordova plugin to make a webview from my website. It's working properly, but two zoom buttons appears when I start to scroll my webpage.
How do I hide it ?
I'm using it to open the webview:

```
var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", "location=no", "closebuttoncaption=Return", "EnableViewPortScale=no");
```

[zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Xly.jpg)

Tks!

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23565487/3419997)

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `zoom` attribute with value `no` as an option when using InAppBrowser.

```
var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", "location=no","zoom=no", "closebuttoncaption=Return", "EnableViewPortScale=no");
```

Source - [Cordova InAppBrowser github documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

Comment: It doesnt work at all. It just disable the zoom but it doesnt hide the zoom buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible. Not supported by Android native api. You can only disable them. Also, keep in mind once you disable zoom controls, user won't be able to pinch and zoom.
Source - [Google Android API Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

The zoom attribute will work if used like this:

var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", "location=no,zoom=no");

Moreover, one can edit the zoomControls in the InAppBrowser.java present in plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/src/android

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br", "_self", {location:"no","zoom=no"});
```